# How to secure appsettings.json file in blazor webassembly wwwroot folder from outside access?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor web assembly project which connects to web API which then connects to the database. The API has its own `appsettings.json` and is secure. But the blazor appsettings.json which is stored in the `wwwroot` folder can be easily accessed from URL like `url/appsettings.json` just like any other file of `wwwroot` folder.

The problem is my appsettings.json in the frontend web assembly project contains some frontend application settings and google OAuth settings which I don't want outside users to read.

My questions are

1. Is there a better way to store the application settings in Blazor webassembly project so that it is more secure and not available to the outside world?
2. If appsettings.json is the only way then is there a way to make it secure so that it is not available to access from outside like from the browser as I explained above?

Comment: Use an API as a middleman for everything you need to do securely or privately. Regard WASM as HTML + JS. Nothing confidential should reside in these spaces. Encryption or the like won't work since the code that will be encrypting/decrypting will be on the client side, which defeats the point. You can of course encrypt user user input. So do your auth on the API by sending user credentials securely to your API.

Comment: @Marius - This is a good idea but can you explain in detail how I would go about using a middleman API to securely talk to a backend API? Let's say I have an azure function that requires a function key so it's not publicly accessible. I can't store that key in the blazor SPA so how does a middleman API securely talk to the backend API?

Comment: @BeanFlicker, you would use an already proven authentication protocol to your API. Once authenticated, return the JSON object. Should be handled the same way you would handle any other sensitive data to a front-end user accessible codebase. Once you have the data, you can work with it to setup other secure services which require private keys you are not willing to expose without proper authentication.

Comment: Do you have have any sample links or do you just assume I know what you are talking about?

Comment: @BeanFlicker, if you need answers to a question at this scale, it's best creating a new question on SO. You are asking for detail in comments which is not the intentional use.